# Two printers / two LANs

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Brother Printer on my LAN at one geographic location and another brother printer on a different LAN in another geographic location. I attach the computer to one LAN at a time and change the default printer in Devices and Printers.. Can the Brother Status Monitor display the status of the printer depending on the location / LAN to which my computer is attached? My status Monitor has only one of the printers listed in the selection box.

Comment: Does the status monitor display the correct printer when you go from one LAN to the other (and, perhaps, restart the software to identify the change in printer)? Or does it only display one and never the other? Windows printers being listed is inevitably going to be different to the status software. Windows will display the printer as it is stored in Registry, however its status (ready, offline etc.) is regularly attempted to be updated by Windows on various things like network changes.

Answer (score 0):

An icon may appear if the printer is the same model and uses the same IP address.

The computer will display two icons:

If the printer is the same model and uses a different IP address;

If the printer is a different model and uses the same IP address;

If the printer is a different model and uses a different IP address;